# How to get value from table's td in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a page with some tables in its source:

```
<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='an'>
    <tr>
        <td width='35%' align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>20</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><
        td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width='361' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='an'>
    <tr>
        <td width='35%' align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XX :</td>
        <td><a href='XXX'><b>XXX</b></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>PHONE :</td>
        <td><b>518878943</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get from this page a phone number, from the second table:

```
<td align='right'>PHONE :</td>
<td><b>518878943</b></td>
```

However, my code:

```
page_src="""<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='an'>
    <tr>
        <td width='35%' align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>20</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><
        td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width='361' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='an'>
    <tr>
        <td width='35%' align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XXX :</td>
        <td><b>XXX</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>XX :</td>
        <td><a href='XXX'><b>XXX</b></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>PHONE :</td>
        <td><b>518878943</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "an"})
for div in divs:
    row = ''
    rows = [row in div.findAll('tbody').findAll('tr')]
```

Gives me such an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 198, in <module>
    rows = [row in div.findAll('tbody').findAll('tr')]
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

How to solve this and get the phone number from the page? Thanks

**EDIT:**

Partly solved. Partly, because I think my solution is ugly, but works. Maybe someone will come up with prettier solution?

```
tds = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "an"})
for div in divs:
    rows = div.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows :
        tds.append(row.findAll('td'))
phone = str(tds[12][1])
phone = phone.replace("<td><b>", "").replace("</b></td>", "").strip()
print phone
```

Comment: Look at the `.text` function, it is much easier than the string `replace` method.

Comment: Guys, thanks for help, I used solution posted by @dstudeba, cheers :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Find the `td` element containing `PHONE :` and then get the [following sibling element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling). One line:

```
soup.find("td", text="PHONE :").find_next_sibling("td").text
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of problems with your code.

```
divs = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "an"})  
for div in divs:
    row = ''
    rows = [row in div.findAll('tbody').findAll('tr')]
```

First problem is there are no `tbody` tags so `div.findAll('tbody')` will return nothing.

Second problem is that `div.findAll('tbody')` would return an array, not a tag, so you can't call `findAll('tr')` on it.

Here is what you want to get all the `tr` tags in the table:

```
divs = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "an"})  
for div in divs:
    row = ''
    rows = div.findAll('tr')
```

You can then go through all the `tr` tags and call `.text` to get the text inside the row, and whichever ones have "PHONE" in them are the ones you want.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "an"})
for div in divs:
    row = ''
    rows = div.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if(row.text.find("PHONE") > -1):
            print(row.text)
```

generates:

```
PHONE :
518878943
```