# get the value of the td tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i need to extract the value of the TD class but unable to extract it

below is my html.

[image: Html Code]

what I tried below

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'day disabled fullcap alertClasstext') and contains(@title,'Slots Full')]")
for elm in elems:
  print(elm.text)
```

it is not printing any value.
i need the values like 23,24,... etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from table's td in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144389/how-to-get-value-from-tables-td-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Nope I already tried with .text, it’s printing blank value

Comment: does it find any tag, like `<body>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a little bit of a detailed xpath, and see if this works.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class=' table-condensed']//tr/td[@class='day disabled fullcap alertClasstext']")
for elm in elems:
  print(elm.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can get the value of a perticular `<td>` tag by using `innerHTML`

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'day disabled fullcap alertClasstext') and contains(@title,'Slots Full')]")
for elm in elems:
    print(elm.innerHTML)
```

Comment: tried above solution got this error below.  AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'innerHTML'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath

```
//td[@title='Off Day']//following-sibling::*
```

to represent the nodes which has `day disabled fullcap alertClasstext` class.

In code :

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@title='Off Day']//following-sibling::*")
for elm in elems:
  print(elm.text)
```

if you just want one of them which is highlighted in the screenshot, try this :

```
elems = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@title='Off Day']//following-sibling::*").text
print(elems.text)
```

Comment: I am getting all the elements like above 28,29,30,1,2 Thank you for answering got to know about sibling concept.